# Отладка скриптов

Tags: php

В web программировании я относительно недавно, но вроде бы знаю уже достаточно, однако недавно возникла серьезная проблема. Суть такова: мне дают задание для какого либо сайта, соответственно, мне нужно узнать принцип работы данного скрипта, какие классы и в каком месте в файловой системе используются, но так все проекты у меня(как и большинство сейчас) это полноценные обьектно-ориентированные системы и структура скрипта состоит из множества подключений из различных библиотек, я не могу нормально разобраться в принципе подключения и использования того или иного класса. Какие есть программы или может быть библиотеки php, которые позволяют получить полную трассировку классов и функций, т.е. при вызове в каком либо скрипте я получал полноценную информацию, откуда подключаются классы, какие функции и методы используются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отладка

- Zend Debugger из Zend Studio
- Расширение Xdebug для PHP
- Работа с кодом(`debug_backtrace`, `debug_print_backtrace`, `var_dump`)

-

```
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```

Тестирование

- PhpUnit - каркас для модульного тестирования

Comment: xDebug уже начинаю осваивать, из того, что я прочитал, я понял, что мне необходимо произвести трассировку моего скрипта, в связи с этим не подскажите еще, какой есть годный визуализатор для логов трассировки для ubuntu, пробывал KCachegrind, но он, похоже, предназначен для профилирования больше.

Comment: Обратите внимание на [trace file parser][1] или [trace gui][2], а также [Xdebug Profiling Web Frontend in PHP][3].

[1]: http://www.rdlt.com/xdebug-trace-file-parser.html
[2]: https://github.com/corretge/xdebug-trace-gui
[3]: https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind

Comment: Большое спасибо за программы, это то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Эм... глазками и ручками + поиск :)
Вот, собственно, и все :)
А в догонку - есть волшебная функция var_dump, которая покажет структуру любого типа объекта.

Так же, можешь в гугле посмотреть результаты по "профилирование кода". Это и есть что-то вроде дебаггера.

Comment: пробывал так делать, кпд по времени уж очень низкий получается, а начальник требует результатов, потому и хочется знать, как это можно автоматизировать.

Comment: Тогда Вам не хватает опыта :)
Хм, а что, документаций никаких к коду нет ? Комментариев тоже нет ? НИчего-ничего нет ?:)))